# weird malloc behavior in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following ANSI C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *buffer = 0;
    int length = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if(f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc(length);
        fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
        fclose (f);
    }
    printf("File size: %d\nBuffer size: %d\nContent: %s\n=END=", length, strlen(buffer), buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Which for some reason after the malloc alocates more memory than needed and output extra garbage from the memory, example:
First run:

```
File size: 12
Buffer size: 22
Content: 123456789012les=$#▬rW|
=END=
```

Second run:

```
File size: 12
Buffer size: 22
Content: 123456789012les↔1↕.'
=END=
```

Third run:

```
File size: 12
Buffer size: 22
Content: 123456789012les=▬kπà
=END=
```

Could someone please help me with this and also explain why my version is behaving weird?
I use MingW TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32bit for compilation (gcc)

Comment: The file text.txt contains: 123456789012

Comment: If `fopen` fails, you have undefined behaviour by derecerencing a null pointer. Put the `printf` into the `if` and makes sure all variables are valid.

Comment: Note: using `0` as _null pointer constant_ is not recommended. Use the macro `NULL`. Even C++ has learned this lesson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) explains why you should be afraid of UB) -because of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). You forgot to add a terminating null byte.

Replace the *faulty* lines:

```
    // WRONG CODE:
    buffer = malloc(length);
    fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
```

with

```
    buffer = malloc(length+1);
    if (!buffer) 
      { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    memset (buffer, 0, length+1);
    if (fread(buffer, 1, length, f) < length) 
      { perror("fread"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>(You could zero just the ending byte; I prefer to clear with `memset` the entire buffer)</sup>

BTW, ANSI C is obsolete. You should use a [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) compliant compiler (e.g. a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) used as `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -g`) and target C11 compliance (or at least [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)). Learn to **use the debugger** (e.g. [`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/))

Read carefully the documentation of [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [fread(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) etc....

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works, however it only work if I put:
if (fread(buffer, 1, length, f) > length)
instead of:
if (fread(buffer, 1, length, f) < length)

Thank you again!

Comment: There's no need to `memset()` the buffer.  Just set the final NUL character with something like this (sans error checks):  `ssize_t result = fread( buffer, 1, length, f); ... buffer[ result ] = '\0';`

Comment: Do people not use `calloc()` any more?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);` invokes undefined behavior.  First, you're not reading in binary mode, so the number of bytes in the file isn't necessarily the number of bytes that will be read.

But if you switch to a binary stream, per 7.19.9.2 of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a
>   `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.

and

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with
>   `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has **undefined behavior for a binary
>   stream** (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any
>   stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in
>   the initial shift state.