# Freeing a struct gives 0

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this piece of code:

```
struct nodo {
    char c;
    int val;
    struct nodo *pizq, *pder;
};
typedef struct nodo NODO;
```

With its proper initializer function:

```
NODO * crea_nodo_int (int valor ) 
{
    NODO *p;
    p = (NODO *)malloc( sizeof( NODO ) );
    if (p == NULL )
        return NULL;
    p -> pizq = NULL;
    p -> pder = NULL;

    p -> val = valor;
    return p;
}
```

On the main function I have:

```
NODO * test = crea_nodo_int(5);
free(test);
inorder(test);
```

As you can see it's an implementation of a binary tree where pizq and pder are left and right children respectively.

However I'm posting this because I had understood that 'free()' actually deallocates memory and I can't see this here. You see, I create node test with value of 5, then free it, then when I walk inorder in the console it prints 
'0' and terminates. Why the hell is printing 0? Shouldn't it go straight to the case where `if (p == NULL) return` and terminate without printing anything? What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code for the inorder function:

```
void inorder( NODO *p )
{
    if (p == NULL) return;

    if( p->pizq != NULL )
        inorder(( p->pizq );

    // Process root
    printf("%d ", p->val );

    if( p->pder != NULL )
        inorder( p->pder );
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc with regard to casting malloc

Comment: This question is incomplete. What is `NODO`?

Comment: @alk a struct...

Comment: You don't have a piece of code... you have a puzzle of code.  Please, send a testable and compilable example of code.... never send pieces of it (the mistake can be elsewhere)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`free(ptr)` deallocates the memory `ptr` pointer is pointing to but `ptr` still points to the freed memory location and accessing such memory is undefined behavior.

Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).

> Notice that this (`free`)function does not change the value of ptr itself, hence it still points to the same (now invalid) location.

So, just calling `free()` will make the pointer a [Dangling Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) that do not point to a valid object of the appropriate type.

After calling `free(ptr)` follow a practice of setting the pointer to `NULL`:

```
ptr = NULL;
```

This will protect against the dangling pointer bugs.

So, in your case, you should -

```
free(test);
test = NULL;
```

Comment: So is there a way to do this? How can I avoid that my inorder walk actually prints something? It's going into the `printf("%d ", p->val );` line which seems un natural to me.

Comment: @DavidMerinos, always remember that **all parameters to functions in C are passed by value** so no way for a function to change the pointer passed to `free(3)`, it will continue pointing to the place you have freed, if you don't take the appropiate measures.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have called `free` on some pointer, you are not allowed to do anything on that memory zone. So you should not call `inorder` (or you might call it *before* `free`).

Your program has [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). Hence its behavior is unpredictable and not explainable (unless you spend years diving into implementation details).

I recommend having several constructor-like functions:

```
NODE*create_leaf_node(int val);
NODE*create_pair_node(NODE*left, NODE*right);
```

and write a (recursive) destructor-like function (which ends by calling `free(n);`):

```
void destroy_node(NODE*n);
```

Of course, I suppose you have your `struct nodo` as in your question, and

```
typedef struct nodo NODE;
```

Your test program might do:

```
NODE*ntest = create_pair_node(create_pair_node(create_leaf_node(1),
                                               NULL),
                              create_leaf_node(3));
inorder(ntest);
destroy_node(ntest), ntest = NULL;
```

(I'm using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in the last statement)

Then compile your program with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Improve it to get no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb` (and perhaps other tools, like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)).

BTW, in C [you should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) ... You might consider displaying (with `perror`) some error message when `malloc` fails then exiting the program, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716494/841108).