# strange seg fault, likely with realloc

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

```
char *dumpTB (TB tb){

    char* text = malloc(sizeof(char));

    int i = 0; // 
    int x = 0; //string index

    tNode* curr = tb->head;

    while(curr != NULL){

        while(curr->line[x] != '\n'){
            printf("%d", i);
            text[i] = curr->line[x];
            printf("%c\n", text[i]);

            text = realloc(text, i+1);

            i++;
            x++;
        }
        text[i] = '\n';
        printf("%c", text[i]);
        text = realloc(text, i+1); 
        i++;

        x = 0; 
        curr = curr->next; 
    }

    return text;
}
```

So I manage to print out the first 12 letters of my string using the print statements but for some reason it gives me a seg fault shortly after printing the 12th letter 'l', and based on the print statements it seems to occur around the realloc...can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
int i = 1; // 
    int x = 0; //string index

    tNode* curr = tb->head;

    while(curr != NULL){

        while(curr->line[x] != '\n'){
            printf("%d", i-1);
            text[i-1] = curr->line[x];
            printf("%c\n", text[i-1]);

            text = realloc(text, i+1);
            i++;
            x++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", i-1);
        text[i-1] = '\n';
        printf("%c", text[i-1]);
        text = realloc(text, i+1); 
        i++;

        x = 0; 
        curr = curr->next; 
        //printf("%c\n", curr->line[0]);
    }
```

I tried fixed the index errors, a really long looking sysmalloc assertion thing which aborts the program.

Comment: If you step through the code line by line with a debugger your problem should become obvious. Hint: What is the value of `i` in the very first call to `realloc`? And what is then the result of `i+1`?

Comment: @GCGSAUCE  What printf statement do you mean?

Comment: Furthermore, if you expect to treat the memory you allocate as a ***null-terminated** byte string*, then you're forgetting one very important thing.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there are only 2 printf statements in the code, its in reference to that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Im really not sure if i am treating it as null-terminated, could u give me a bigger clue as to what you mean?

Comment: Consider giving some [MCVE]. In its current form, your code is not one, we don't know what `TB` is, and we should not even try to guess.

Comment: The pointer that you return, will you pass it to `strlen`? Will you do e.g. `printf("%s", returned_pointer)`? Will you treat it as a *string*? Then it needs to be *terminated* by a zero (the "null"). [Any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told you that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), so [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108) it if you have it. As explained by [AnT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47913637/841108), you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) because of a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Fix that as soon as possible. Be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB and take more time to read about it (it is tricky).

Also, remember that both [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and [realloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) are somehow expensive calls (for some suitable notion of expensive; actually, they are quite fast - often less than a microsecond on a desktop for reasonable use), and they could fail (by giving `NULL`) and you should [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716494/841108) that.

In practice, you'll better use `realloc` less often. As a rule of thumb, you want to keep both the used length and the allocated size somewhere (e.g. in additional local variables), and you might use some geometrical progression (e.g.  `newsize = 4*oldsize/3 + 10`....) to avoid too frequent `realloc`-s. Doing a `realloc` for each additional byte is ugly.

Compile your code with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. [Use the debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) `gdb`  and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and other trouble.

Comment: I know it's ugly but I didn't want to have to free any unused bytes so I thought this might be simpler since it's dynamic. I edited my question to include revised code, is this what you guys mean by fixing the undefined behavior?

Comment: It is not simpler, and it is inefficient. And your code is wrong.

Comment: Also, UB has a well defined meaning (follow the links I gave in my answer above).

Comment: Yes, the constant reallocing is a habit you should break out of quickly before it becomes too ingrained.