# How can I get a file's size in C without using either fseek or stat?

Tags: c, file, size

I'm doing a project for my school and I can't find out how to get the size of a file. Since I need to read a script and use it in my program, I need the size of the file to use either read or fread.

Here is what I've done to get the file size but it doesn't seem to work.

```
int my_size(int filedesc)
{
    int size = 1;
    int read_output = 1;
    char *buffer;

    for (size = 1; read_output != 0 ; size++) {
        buffer = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char*));
        read_output = read(filedesc, buffer, size);
        free(buffer);
    }
    return(size);
}
```

And I'm not allowed to use stat() nor fseek() as rules for this project nor can I use read or fread with an arbitrary size like 100 since scripts given can be either small or big.

Comment: If you can't use `fseek`, you will need to implement your own `fseek`, like in [this exercise](http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/Ex_8.4.html)

Comment: You could do `size_t count = 0; while (getchar() != EOF) count++;` — but why can't you use `fseek()` plus `ftell()` or `stat()` (and presumably `fstat()` isn't allowed either)?  What's the motivation behind rejecting those?  Could your input be coming from a terminal or pipe or other non-seekable (non-repeatable) device?  Do you need to save a copy of the file contents?

Comment: @Useless : Doing repeatedly _read()_ as you do above, you won't get the correct size, as _read()_ function will read from the offset set by previous read operation.

Comment: Your code is peculiar.  You start of by excluding the possibility that the file is empty.  You allocate space for 2 bytes; you read one byte; you release the buffer; you increment `size` by `1` to 2; you allocate 3 bytes; you read 2 bytes; you free, and increment size by `1` to 3; you allocate 4 bytes; you read 3 bytes; you free, and increment `size` to 4 (but you've now read 6 bytes); and you continue.

Comment: That is a terrible way to find a file size, it is very inefficient.  You can avoid `stat` by using `fstat`, since the file is already open.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't use them since these functions are banned in this project (my school allows very few function thus forcing us to "think outside the box") and I haven't thought of the possibility that the file could be empty.
And I see now thanks to you that my malloc is flawed.

Comment: @cdarke Sadly, fstat is a banned function :/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Yet - just to clarify things - the problem is not that he allocates one extra byte. The issue here is that he is not taking into account that the offset is changing with each read() operation! And as you correctly mentioned, he doesn't count the bytes already read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can rely on the input to be a *persistent* file (i.e. residing on storage media), and on that file not being modified during your program's run, then you could pre-read it to the end to count the bytes in it, then rewind.

But outside of an academic exercise, the usual reason to forbid measuring the size via `stat()`, `fseek()`, and similar is that the input *might not* reside on storage media, so that

1. you cannot determine its size without reading it, but also
2. you cannot rewind it or seek within it.

The trick then is not how to determine the size in advance, but rather how to *do without* measuring the size in advance.  There are at least two main strategies for that:

- Don't rely on storing the whole contents in memory at once in the first place.  Instead, operate on its contents as they are read, maintaining only enough in memory at any given time to do so.
- Alternatively, adapt dynamically to the file size.  There are many variations on this. For example, if you're just reading the file into a monolithic block then you can `malloc()` space and `realloc()` when you find you need more.  Or you could store the contents in a linked list, allocating new list nodes as needed.

As for the approach presented in the question, there are several issues with it.  It appears to be an attempt to do as I first described -- reading the file to the end to determine its size -- but

1. It seems to assume that each `read()` will start at the beginning of the file, or perhaps that `read()` will fail if it cannot read the full file.  Neither is the case.  Each `read()` will start at the file's current position, and will leave the file positioned after the last byte transferred.
2. Because it changes the file position, your approach will require the file to be rewound after -- via `lseek()`, for example.  But if `lseek()` can be used for that purpose (and note well my previous comments with respect to files in which you cannot seek), then it would provide a much cleaner approach to measuring the file's size.
3. You do not account for I/O errors.  If one occurred then it would probably send your program into an infinite loop.
4. Dynamic allocation is comparatively expensive, and you're doing a whole lot of it.  If you want to implement the pre-reading strategy, then this would be a better implementation:

   ```
   ssize_t count_bytes(int fd) {
       ssize_t num_bytes = 0;
       char buffer[2048];
       ssize_t result;

       do {
           result = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
           if (result < 0) {
               // handle error ...
           }
           num_bytes += result;
       while (result > 0);

       return num_bytes;
   }
   ```

Comment: I see how I could improve my code but `realloc()` is forbidden and I'm not skilled enough with linked lists to use them.

Comment: As the number of bytes in a file can exceed `SIZE_MAX`, using the widest integer type `uintmax_t` could be useful to accumulate the file size.

Comment: @Useless, in that case, the constraints on the exercise seem to be designed to force you to employ the first strategy I described: "Don't rely on storing the whole contents in memory at once in the first place."  I'm especially inclined to think so if "not skilled enough with linked lists" can be broadened to "not *expected to be* skilled enough with linked lists [...]."

Comment: @JohnBollinger you have pretty much explained every thing I needed to get over this problem and found an alternative to it (since what you proposed contradicts my school coding style). And found a way using malloc() and adapt it dynamically to the file size but it is still is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), or [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), on your executable, to be compiled with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Read carefully the documentation of [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), and of every function you are using (including [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), whose failure you forgot to [test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32716494/841108)).

You need to use the result (actually read byte count) of [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html). And you need to handle the error case (when [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) gives -1) specially.

What is probably happenning, with a long enough file, is that on the first loop you are reading 1 byte, on the second loop you are reading 2 bytes, on the third loop you have read 3 bytes, etc... (and you forgot to compute 1+2+3 in that case).

You should cumulate and sum all the `read_output`  and you should handle the case when [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) gives less than the `size` (this should happen the last time your `read` gave non zero).

I would instead suggest using a *fixed* buffer (of constant or fixed size), and repeatedly do a [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) but carefully using the returned byte count (also, handle errors, and EOF condition).

Be aware that [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) are quite expensive. As a rule of thumb, you should [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) a buffer of several kilobytes (and handle carefully the returned byte count, also testing it against errors, see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)). A program [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing only a few bytes at once each time is inefficient.

Also, `malloc` (or `realloc`) is quite expensive. Incrementing the [heap allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) size by one is ugly (since you call `malloc` on every loop; in your case you don't even need to use `malloc`). You'll better use some geometric progression, perhaps `newsize = 4*oldsize/3 + 10;` (or similar).

Comment: I've reread the manual of read(2) and figured out I've misused read I shouldn't have used it like in my example.